# How to hover over a div to change just a part of its background?

Tags: css

I've searched a lot about it and found how to change another div's content on hovering over one div and also found out how to change its elements-- like background color, font, font color.

This is what I've been able to get so far

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="stylesheet.css"/>
        <title>Fancy Fonts</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="test">
            Change me on hover!
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
div.test
{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
}

div.test:hover
{
    background-color: grey;
}
```

But this changes the whole div's background color, I need it to change, say, just its upper half, *but* no JS or anything, *only* CSS.

Comment: I think that you will need extra elements i.e. divs, spans within your div to have extra control and modify them. This way the upper half could be another div, or a part within the middle, a span and so on. Are you restricted to only using a single div?

Comment: Not really, but it's preferable; though, the trick suggest by Paulie_D seems to work very nicely, so, I think I'll go with that. Thanks anyway. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with a gradient.

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/Dm8ma/)

```
.test {
     height:100px;
     background:linear-gradient(black 50%,red 50%, red); 
}

.test:hover {
     background:linear-gradient(green 50%,red 50%, red);
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

[Fiddle<---](http://jsfiddle.net/lacoolj/Q8N3H/)

Adding an inner `div` let's you separate these colors if needed.  You need a height value to accomplish this though.

**CSS:**

```
div.test{
    background-color: black;
    color: white;
    height: 20px;
}

div.bg:hover{
    background-color: grey;
}
div.bg {
    background-color: transparent;
    max-height: 50%;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="test">
    <div class="bg">
    Change me on hover!
    </div>
</div>
```